# How get a value from child components with quasar Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to create a single component with 3 q-radio then listen to the value of props in a parent component but it doesn't work.

The code of my q-radio components:

```
<template>
  <div class="row content-center justify-around">
    <div>
      <q-radio
        :val="value"
        model-value="walking"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_walk"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <q-radio
        :val="value"
        model-value="cycling"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_bike"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <q-radio
        :val="value"
        model-value="driving"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_car" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TravelChoice",

  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

And the code from my parent page:

```
<template>
  <TravelChoice :value="choice" v-model="choice" />
</template>

<script>
  import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue"
  import TravelChoice from "components/button/TravelChoice.vue"

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "Home",

    components: {
      TravelChoice
    },

    setup() {
      return {
        choice: ref("walking")
      }
    },

    watch: {
      choice(val){
        console.log(val)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

The component is displayed but impossible to change the default choice.
The problem occurs because I have 3 components as props ?

Answer (score 1):

`value` props should be renamed to `modelValue`, then assign to `val` prop the current value that you're using for `model-value`, then use `@update:model-value` event to emit the new val

```html
<template>
  <div class="row content-center justify-around">
    <div>
      <q-radio
        val="walking"
        @update:model-value="emitVal"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_walk"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <q-radio
         val="cycling"
         @update:model-value="emitVal"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_bike"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <q-radio
         val="driving"
         @update:model-value="emitVal"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_car" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TravelChoice",

  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods:{
    emitVal(value){
      this.$emit('update:model-value',value)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Now, the value is correctly returned but now I have a new problem: "Missing required prop: 'modelValue' ".
However I do send the value in the props: "<TravelChoice :modelValue="choice" v-model="choice" />"